# Node.js Tutorial Triggers all App Engine VM Instances

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, virtual-machine

I followed the tutorial outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

with `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');

var app = express();


// [START hello_world]
// Say hello!
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Hello, world!');
});
// [END hello_world]

if (module === require.main) {
  // [START server]
  // Start the server
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
  });
  // [END server]
}

module.exports = app;
```

Upon deploying to app engine, though the script is very simple, referencing the VM instances, it justifies bringing up 8 different instances:

[image]

Is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you do a `gcloud preview app deploy`, we create a new version of that application.  Each version comes (by default) with 2 VMs.  Looking at your list of VMs - I think I'm seeing ~5 different versions deployed.

To stop the old versions, go to the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com), and use the UI to stop each old (non-default) version:

[image: versions ui]

That should get you back to where you expect.  We are changing our tools (in the next few weeks) so that these stop automatically for you.

Hope this helps!